# Ruby on Rails multiple redirect after deleting items in cart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, testing, cart, destroy

my code

```
def destroy
    @line_item = LineItem.find(params[:id])
    @line_item.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
    if current_cart.line_items.empty?
      format.html {redirect_to store_path, notice: 'Your cart is empty'}
    else
      format.html { redirect_to current_cart, notice:'Product removed.' }
    end
      format.xml  { head :ok }
    end
  end
```

my test

```
test "should destroy line_item" do
    assert_difference('LineItem.count', -1) do
      delete :destroy, id: @line_item
    end

    assert_redirected_to Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
end
```

how can i test my multiple redirections if my cart ist empty?

Comment: Tip: Select the text and use Ctrl+k to format the selected text into code (or indent it with 4 spaces before)

Comment: What do you mean with " if my cart ist empty?" , do yo mean if is empty or not empty? let me know and will give you the answer

Comment: can you try to use  " .nil? "  instead of ".empty?"   ?